# Calculate remainder when $2^{403}$ is divided by 22

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> Find $2^{403}$ mod $22$.

I tried using FLT but since 22 is not prime then I can't, so I'm stuck on how to break down $2^{403}$ so its easier to compute the remainder.

Comment: Use fermats little theorem in conjunction with chinese remainder theorem.  What is the remainder of $2^{403}$ when divided by $11$?  What is the remainder of $2^{403}$ when divided by $2$?  How do you combine this information?

Comment: $2^{403}$ = 8 (mod 11) and $2^{403}$ = 0 (mod 2) so $2^{403}$ = 8 (mod 22)?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619). If it were up to me I would instaclose this as a duplicate, but I have promised not to. Instead, I downvote answers by experienced users unless their answer brings up an unusual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $2^{403}=r+22 q$ with $q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $r$ is even and 
$2^{402}=r'+11 q$, where $r=2r'$.

Now note that $11$ is prime and by  Fermat's little theorem $2^{402}=2^{10\cdot 40}4\equiv 4$ mod $11$.

Therefore $2^{403} \equiv 2\cdot 4\equiv 8$ mod $22$.

Comment: I got a downvote. That's fine. But I am really curious to know if something is wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$2^{403} \equiv 0$ mod $2$, and $2^{403}=2^{10 \times 40} 2^{3} \equiv 8$ mod $11$, by Fermats little theorem. By the Chinese remainder theorem, $2^{403} \equiv 8$ mod $22$.

Comment: What part of the CRT allows us to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the Chinese Remainder Theorem slipped your mind.  You can always reason:

$2^{403} = 22k + r$ and as $22$ and $2^{403}$ are even then $r$ is even.

$2^{403} = 22k + 2s$ so $2^{402} = 11k + s$.  *Now* you can use $FLT$.

$2^{10}\equiv 1 \mod 11$ so $2^{402} \equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \mod 11$.

So $s =4$ and $r = 8$.

... But as others have pointed out CRT theorem addresses just this problem.